# Load MrSID file in QGIS 2.2 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, imagery, mrsid

Is there a way to do this? I have tried a number of the write ups on this, and it appears that libgdal-mrsid-src no longer exists. Is there any other workaround? USDA NAIP imagery is sent as MrSID.