# How to import a .sid Raster File in QGIS 2.6.0 On Linux Mint 17

Tags: qgis, linux, mrsid, linux-mint

I need some help importing MrSID Raster files in QGIS. I am running 2.6.0 on Linux Mint 17. After an internet search I have found a couple of resources that are perhaps outdated. The most promising is found here :

http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/TutorialMrSid

However when I attempted to follow the instructions my terminal and I could not find the file "libgdal-mrsid-src" on either the stable or unstable Ubuntu GIS repos. Has anyone had success or could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: There are similar questions: [Load MrSID file in QGIS 2.2 on Ubuntu 13.10](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87985/load-mrsid-file-in-qgis-2-2-on-ubuntu-13-10); [Adding MrSid to QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87933/adding-mrsid-to-qgis). Without accepted answers though.

Comment: Ubuntugis unstable had support for MrSid with GDAL 1.9.0 for Ubuntu Oneiric and lucid. The tutorial uses this package. Unfortunately, nobody has built newer packages.

Comment: Just another tutorial: https://gist.github.com/oeon/6527004

Answer (score 2):

I also found great difficulty with mrsid type files in my Linux Mint QGIS setup. A very simple solution was to install WINE from the mint software repository so that I could use some Windows programs. 
Then I downloaded a Mrsid viewer application for windows from the US Library of Congress that also can export a SID file as a GeoTiff. Worked perfectly, and the embedded projection info within the SID files was retained in the resulting GeoTiff. Each one takes about 5 seconds to convert.
The viewer does not require that WINE have microsoft.net framework present, which is a problem with WINE. Viewer link here: 
http://memory.loc.gov/ammem/help/download_sid.html

Quick and dirty, but gets my gis work done.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the LizardTech SDK in GDAL per link you reference is probably the best solution, but I also found this pretty daunting.

Here is another alternative for Linux - LizardTech now has their geoexpress command line utilities available for Linux, available at no cost (thanks LizardTech) - http://www.lizardtech.com/downloads/category/#tools__utilities

You can use the mrsidgeodecode utility to convert a mrsid file to several other image formats.  I test with sid to geotif.  Once you have a GDAL accessible file, you can easily handle and edit the file, with GDAL utilities, or QGIS.

Comment: "LizardTech" is now "Extensis" and that link goes nowhere. Can't find these tools on the Extensis web site.

Comment: but see here: https://help.extensis.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012322354-Enable-MrSID-in-QGIS